# Load more button with two column layout

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

Currently I am using bootstrap to create and then with php dynamically populate two columns

```
<?php if(have_rows(): ?>
<div class="col-lg-6>
<?php while(have_rows()): the_row; ?>
//load odd rows
<div class="reviews"></div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-6>
<?php while(have_rows()): the_row; ?>
//load even rows
<div class="reviews"></div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
<div id="load" class="submit cta">
    <a href="#">Load More</a>
</div>
```

Then with javascript I am counting the odd and even rows and only displaying the first four.

```
$(function(){
  $(".reviews").slice(0, 4).show(); // select the first 4
  $("#load").click(function(e){ // click event for load more
     e.preventDefault();
     $(".reviews:hidden").slice(0, 8).show(); // select next 4 hidden divs and show them
     if($(".reviews:hidden").length == 0){ // check if any hidden divs still exist
        $('#load').hide(); // alert if there are none left
     }
  });
});
```

How would I write the javascript so that it display the first two items from each column then loads the next two when the load more button is clicked?

Comment: Most often there is ever a better way, so to answer your question: Yes. However if you're interested in anything more specific for the code, please edit your question and write it out.

Comment: @hakre I changed my question. I am stumped and don't know how to make the load more button work like this. https://www.kohlerwalkinbath.com/reviews/